# How can I fix my scope issues, after abstracting ajax functions into a provider-object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, scope

I have a front controller pattern based java web application. I have recently refactored a big part of the javascript of said application. I have abstracted all of the javascript functions which makes calls to the database, due to new requirements of logging all communication events. My js-file consists of 30-some delete-, insert-, and update-functions, which are now globally available to the web application, if the file is imported to a page.

But I've run into a problem. I use ajax functions to send or retrieve info from the database, and use the success/fail-functions to decide if a page should reload, an error message should be displayed, or anything else. However, after abstracting all of the ajax calls into a seperate .js-file, I am experiencing what seems to be scope issues.

All of my functions are bound to an object, for easy identification of where the function belongs. This might be part of the problem, but if it isn't, I like the overview it gives me of where the function comes from. Much like a static function in java, which is referenced by both it's class name, and method name.

See the following example:

```
var provider = {};
provider.insertEntry = function(personID, teamID){

    var jsonDataObject = getDefaultJsonDataObject(); //this one returns an object, containing the logging settings (from cookie)
    jsonDataObject.personID = personID;
    jsonDataObject.teamID = teamID;
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonDataObject);

    $.getJSON("insertentry", {
        json : jsonData
    }, function(data) {
    }).success(function() {
        parent.$.colorbox.close();
        parent.window.location.href = parentpageaction+'?teamid='+teamID; 
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
};
```

Now, the ajax call executes as it should, but the three functions within the success-function seems to be out of scope. the first is meant to close an instance of [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), containing the editor-page, which calls the ajax in the first place. The second line reloads the parent page, meaning the url that is actually showing in the browser, considering the ajax-calling page exists in an iFrame within the colorbox.

All this worked perfectly, when i defined the function directly in a javascript script tag, within the jsp-file of the page contained in the colorbox. Now it doesn't, but no error messages are shown either. I know the success function is called, but the scope is different.

I've also tried to make the ajax-function return a boolean when ready, but due to ajax' asynchronous nature, this didn't work either...

So: How can I fix my scope issues, after abstracting ajax functions into a provider-object? Where exactly am I going wrong? Is this architecture a good idea at all, or am I lost, and need to revert?

Comment: Have you tried storing `this` in a variable before it gets out of scope?

Comment: Can you show how .insertEntry() is called?  Like szupie mentioned, "this" seems to be missing -- it would probably help with figuring out what "parent" is referring to.

Comment: insertEntry is called in an onclick function, using the syntax `provider.insertEntry(99, 99);`. In the meantime, I've made it work, simply by removing the line of code referring to the colorbox. The parent.window.location.href works, and closes the popup anyway. I don't understand the full extent of my issue, but my required behaviour actually works now.

Comment: Strike that... It worked yesterday. Now it doesn't again... I don't get this...

Comment: On second thought, The ajax is called by a form submit-button. When abstracting away some of the javascript functionality, I most certainly have discarded some disabling of the standard submit, leaving the page (popup) to refresh itself, before the ajax success function is executed. The problem is most likely not scope, but a race condition.

Comment: True true.

My problem was very far away from what I assumed, and the solution is not even closely relevant to the title. This question is most likely unsalvageable, so I'll delete it. Thanks to you @HarryPehkonen, for asking how the function was called. That was the nudge I needed to get on track to find the actual problem. Hyyva!